# Plugs won't stay in wall receptacle

Tags: electrical

We bought a new house 25 years ago. The wall plug receptacles never from day one would hold a plug. Are they defective or are there springs missing that would keep them in place? Can they be adjusted or do I need to replace them all? All my receptacles have the third prong opening for ground.

Comment: Where in the world are you? Socket designs vary significantly between countries, which could affect the answer.

Comment: Safe to say, not BS1363

Comment: I really think this question should be closed until it is [edit]ed to provide an answer to @DavidRicherby's question.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely replace as many as you can. Residential grade receptacles from that era are/were total junk.

If you can, I would definitely get "spec-grade" receptacles. These are commercial duty devices that are MUCH better than resi grade stuff.

Also, I agree, you will most likely have to install TR, or tamper-resistant, receptacles, which is not necessarily a bad thing.

For a 25 year old home most areas requiring GFI protection will already have it, but you will have to add them in some areas like protecting all kitchen counter receptacles. They don't all need to be GFI devices, just GFI protected.

Please ask if you are not sure of the requirements.

Answer (score 7):

Replace them.  There's no way to adjust them.  This is a common problem with receptacles, when they're worn they don't hold plugs as well.

Depending on your location, you may be required to install tamper resistant receptacles in most living areas.  GFCI receptacles may be required in some areas as well.

Comment: +1. Receptacles all wear out and replacing them is a pretty easy DIY job. Just make sure you get the right kind for your area (tamper-resistant, GFCI where necessary, etc.)

Comment: They are generally inexpensive too, so even if they could be repaired somehow, the amount of time and effort would not make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the wall sockets if at all possible.

Until then, here's what I do.  (I should mention I'm in the USA.)  On the plug, either bend the prongs in/out, or apply some torque to them to make them slant.  Either approach will help the prongs make stronger contact with the sockets.  Try a little bending at first, then more until you're happy with the result.

If they're solid prongs, then you probably want to bend them slightly in.  I've done this a fair amount, particularly with brand new plugs that seem to slide out at the slightest provocation.

Multi-piece prongs seem to handle the torque a little better.  These are the prongs with two flat pieces side by side.  With those you can sometimes insert a flat screwdriver between the pieces and twist a little.  This will convert the flat prong to a fat prong. (I think this was the point of the multi-piece prongs.  It may be the advice on them that got me into hacking plugs.)

If you end up bending the prongs too much for easy plugging, there are tricks for that, too.  Say the prongs have to be bent very close together for a snug fit, but end up being too close together to slide in easily.  Just angle the plug to put in one prong at at time, then push to the side to ease the other prong in.  In fact, if this is a problem then bending the plugs outward can make insertion easier.

Be VERY CAREFUL in any case.  And be prepared to replace plugs after breaking them.

Good luck.  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Your suggestion about bending prongs seems to assume a specific kind of plug. The prongs of UK plugs are very solid (6.4mm x 4mm cross-section brass) and would not be bendable by hand; European round-pin plugs also aren't very bendable.

Comment: My reply was USA-centric.  Should it be removed?

Comment: I don't think there's any need to remove it but I'd recommend editing it to say that you're talking about US plugs.

Answer (score 0):

It's just worn out and not safe. Replace them with new ones they're likely cheaper by the box than individually at big box stores. Kill the breaker and verify it's dead before doing the work. 
Bending your plugs to get around a worn socket is at best a temporary solution and at worst a fire hazard. A lose connection will have a higher resistance which causes heat.

It would be a good idea to get one of those neon socket testers while you're there that verify the hot and neutral are on the right side of the socket and the ground is actually grounded. They're cheap.

Note US based answer.